# Read External SD card

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, external-sd, mount, motorola-xoom

I have a Xoom 2 media edition MZ608-32 3G, immediately after receiving it I upgraded it to ICS 4.0.4 and rooted it.

However the beast won't mount any SD card that is put in its external storage.

I have a 32G sd card that is formatted as fat32, it reads perfectly well on my p1000 and the PC. window's chkdsk also said disk is OK, so the problem is the xoom.

Does anyone know of a solution to make the xoom mount the card properly?